# Does nginx require the set_real_ip_from directive for $http_x_forwarded_for header?

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

Do I need the below nginx directives if I use Cloudflare and leverage the header "$http_x_forwarded_for" which incoming requests include by default?

```
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;

real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
#real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

Here's my nginx log directive:

```
  # format: e.g., $http_cf_ipcountry derives from the Cloudflare header HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY;
  # the others too follow this format
  log_format complete '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                      '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                      '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$host" '
                      '"$http_x_forwarded_for" "$http_cf_ipcountry" "$http_accept_language"';
```

I'm just not understanding why I'd need to use the first block if the second one (the log directive) works? Cloudflare recommends the first block here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170786

My log files appear to be working great, but when I read about the above directive I became confused, as if I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: The [ngx_http_realip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) is used to set the value of `$remote_addr` by using the value of `$http_x_forwarded_for`, because sometimes you need `$remote_addr` to be the client's IP address and not the downstream proxy's.

Comment: From link above: Cloudflare includes the original visitor IP address in the X-Forwarded-For and CF-Connecting-IP headers.

Comment: I know. The realip module is about moving that value into the `$remote_addr` variable.

Comment: Richard, I guess I'm confused. If this is already occurring, why does the http_x_forwarded_for header sometimes read an empty value ... even when the remote_addr header has a value? I presume it's because the user is directly connecting so there's no proxy/cdn, but in other cases, the values are different when users connect through a proxy/cdn (in my case Cloudflare).

Comment: Oh okay, I think you're saying the first block will do this for us so that the values are the same? But either way, w/o the block it's happening already.

Comment: Make sure you update the set_real_ip_from dynamically : https://maxmastalerz.com/blog/dynamically-generating-set-real-ip-from-for-cloudflare-i-ps-in-nginx